# Oracle Database package compilation history and errors logging

Tags: database, oracle, compilation, compiler-errors, oracle11g

I compiled a package on Oracle 11g DB and it gave me errors.  I tried fetching the errors, but meanwhile someone fixed it and now I have no way to know what exactly the issue was in the first place.

Is there any way I can get a history of the compilation of a package and the errors encountered with each compilation?

Thanks for your help.  Please let me know if more information is required.

--
Sid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, no, a history of that information is not available.

Comment: Thanks.  I just wanted to be sure.